# Typical Runoff velocity values

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, cfd, hydrology

I am computing runoff velocities for rainfall falling over an area using St-Venant 1D momentum equation. I wanted to have some idea if my computed velocities are  within a reasonable range of what one can expect in real life. I was wondering what are the typical values one can expect in real life. I understand that there are many factors which influence the velocity, for example - keeping slope constant, land cover will influence the velocity a lot. Appreciate any inputs you can provide.

Note that at this point I don't have access to any experimental data to validate my model results.

Answer (score 0):

Surface runoff velocity is typically less than 1 ft/sec. It depends on slope and surface covering, but that is a ballpark value. More info at https://www.lmnoeng.com/Hydrology/hydrology.php